# Get year and month formatted in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to get the year and month in JavaScript in a specific format, but cannot figure out how. I need it like this:

`2022-03`

I've tried using these functions but I need the 0 in the month:

```
console.log(new Date().getFullYear())
console.log(new Date().getMonth() + 1)
```

but the result is `2022` and `3`

How can I format dates in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, append leading zero to date and slice last two digits

```js
let d = new Date();
date = [
  d.getFullYear(),
  ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2)
].join('-');

console.log(date)
```

Comment: Why not just use the String.padLeft method instead of concatenating and slicing

Comment: You can surely, the answer is what it come to me on the spot

Comment: would this also add a 0 to double digit months?

Comment: Nope it wont, as we take the last two chars :), you can just try to his out on console like `('0' + 11).slice(-2)`

Comment: @tHatpart If the answer helped, can you please mark it as an answer and upvote?